# block_views module doesn't show created views

Tags: views

I installed the [Block Views Visibility](https://drupal.org/project/block_views) module on Drupal 7.23. I cleared the cache with `drush cc all`. There are several views I created. I also created a new block. If I click 'Views' there are no views except 'all_articles_view: Page' which I didn't create.

Do I have to do additional things?

Comment: did you go into admin/config/block_views

Comment: do you mean in backend? Under configuration there isn't a block_view entry.

Comment: Should the new [module entry appear here](http://imageshack.com/a/img200/8977/7wfb.png)?

Comment: are your views of pages type ?

Comment: At the moment I only work with blocks.

Comment: i'm seeing a view i didn't create: [link](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4473/34d1.png) would be great if someone has a more descriptive how to configure.